# .NET Console App with Entity Framework Core: 'The process has no package identity' only when started without debugging

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, discord, dsharp+

I have a .NET Console App integrated with Entity Framework and Discord Sharp Plus with the following libraries:

- DSharpPlus
- DSharpPlus.CommandsNext
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Running the application without debugging (Control + F5 in Visual Studio) works just fine, no crashes issued.

However, if I run with debugging, upon accessing my `DbContext`, I get an error

> InvalidOperationException: The Process has no package identity (0x80073D54)

An example being this line:

```
Database.Commands.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CommandTrigger == name)
```

For debugging purposes, if I change `SingleOrDefault` to `ElementAt(0)`, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet .ElementAtOrDefault(__p_0)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed.   This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)

This is NOT an UWP app. It is a .NET console application with several class libraries.

Here's my Dbcontext class:

```cs
private readonly string dbPath = $"Data Source={Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YuutaDbPath")}";

public DbSet<Guild> Guilds { get; set; }
// ...
// ...

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    => options.UseSqlite(dbPath);

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.SeedEnumValues//....
}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving your EF connection string or any other setting? I've seen similiar obscure problems with settings logic in Windows 10.

Comment: @halliba For now, it's a simple environment variable: `private readonly string dbPath = $"Data Source={Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YuutaDbPath")}";` and in `OnConfiguring`: `options.UseSqlite(dbPath)`

Comment: Which EF core version is this? I think I got  similar error (to "his may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core") when I migrated from 2.2 to 3.1...

Comment: @cantSleepNow 3.1.5

Comment: I think is a EF isssue. I saw this error message on initial Add-Migration, in a old project. I had to remove ef core and reinstall, migrate .. and run..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is could be an internal exception which is handled by EF Core. You will see this kind of exceptions if you have disabled '[Enable Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019)' in Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Debugging

[image]
Enabling this option should fix the issue.

Essentially this will break code execution when exception occurs outside of your code even if handled.

If you hit F5 when the exception occurs it should continue running - this is way your program is running without issues when there is not debugger attached.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's really bad that Microsoft does not manage to create code without exception while in normal behavior.

Comment: but you didn't say the root cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have [read](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1058) that this exception can occur when not using a fully qualified path on the connection string. Make sure that your database path in your connection is fully qualified in the following form:

```
var dbPath = @"Filename=C:\the\path\to\your\database.db";
```

You can decide on whether this full string is in the environment variable or whether you just have the path as an environment variable.

Comment: `Filename`? Isn't it `Data Source`?

Comment: Setting the fully qualified path didn't help unfortunately, with both `Filename` and `Data Source`

Comment: I've seen mixed information about using `Filename` vs. `Data Source`. My only suggestion is to make sure the environment variable resolves a valid path. Maybe you can try a secondary console application that simply tests connecting with a hardcoded connection string.

Comment: As I said, I hardcoded the path with no luck unfortunately